# How to have one DataSet be used by multiple DataSources

Tags: birt, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing a Birt ODA driver to access services. For this I have created A specific datasource (In my case for talking to a BlazeDS service) and a very generic DataSet that does the query evaluation. https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Amf-Datasource+for+Birt

My Idea now is to create a Spring Datasource that allows me to switch the DataSource in the report from the BlazeDS to the Spring Datasource and access the services directly without any marshalling and unmarshalling.

Unfortunately it seems the DataSet is directly couppled with the DataSource (At least if I use the template in Eclipse that generates the stub for a custom DataSource and DataSet).

So is there a way do decouple the DataSource and the DataSet and use one DataSet with multiple DataSources (optionally even as a Standallone version withouth any DataSource ... as this one would work on input provided by data-binding).

Chris

Comment: When do you want to change the datasource - at design time, at deployment time or programmatically? If the latter, what do you want to determine the datasource - a parameter, data retrieved from anotherr datasource, or something else?